# Regex that looks for two different digits and doesn't allow for any word character

Tags: regex

So far i have come up with following regex that allows me to find only entries with two different digits:

```
.*([0-9])\1*(?!\1)[0-9]+.*
```

but for the love of me I don't know how I exclude any word character: `a-zA-Z` from this.

You can see it here: https://regex101.com/r/Uaf1Az/12

The last three lines shouldn't be matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use anchors to assert the start `^` and the end `$` of the string and exclude matching chars a-z or a newline using a negated character class.

```
^[^a-zA-Z\r\n]*([0-9])\1*(?!\1)[0-9]+[^a-zA-Z\r\n]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0JiT4p/1)

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you  replace `.*` with line boundaries?

```
 ^([0-9])\1*(?!\1)[0-9]+$
```

https://regex101.com/r/Uaf1Az/13

Comment: i can add line boundaries, doesn't make really a difference to me, but not replace them cause than any characters like +() wouldn't work anymore as you can see in the link that you posted.
But then i am still at the same place as before.